# i need to migrate a java EE, jsf, jboss eap 6.3 primefaces app to wildfly 8.2.1

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, mojarra

migrate java EE application, jsf, jboss eap 6.3 primefaces to wildfly 8.2.1.

The application works normally on jboss 6.3.
After deploying the application on wildfly 8 the application is buggy.
Deploy is normally done by eclipse, but during browsing problems appear.

my list is neither empty nor null for autocomplete

The converter that is in autocomplete is not being called

I tried replacing the jsf annotations @ManagedBean with @Named from the cdi.
I changed the jar
\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\modules\system\layers\base\javax\faces\api\main

jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8
who is on wildfly
per
jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1 which is in eap
I'm having null pointers exceptions while navigating the screens.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
<artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
<version>2.1.19</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
<artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
<version>2.1.19</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-8) Error Rendering View[/sistema/paginas/requisicao/papelaria/manterRequisicaoPapelaria.xhtml]: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeSuggestionsAsList(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:516) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeSuggestions(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:411) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeResults(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:122) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeEnd(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:104) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:543) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1689) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:383) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:302) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:60) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:219) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1004) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:421) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at br.gov.camara.cotasgraf.controle.util.SelecaoSolicitanteFiltro.doFilter(SelecaoSolicitanteFiltro.java:58) [classes:]
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at br.gov.camara.cotasgraf.controle.util.EncodeFiltro.doFilter(EncodeFiltro.java:38) [classes:]
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at br.gov.camara.cotasgraf.controle.util.CacheFiltro.doFilter(CacheFiltro.java:42) [classes:]
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:248) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:77) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:167) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:761) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]

2021-12-02 08:17:18,943 SEVERE [org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandler] (default task-8) FullAjaxExceptionHandler: An exception occurred during rendering JSF ajax response. Error page '/error.xhtml?faces-redirect=true' will be shown.: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeSuggestionsAsList(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:516) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeSuggestions(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:411) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeResults(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:122) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeEnd(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:104) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:543) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1689) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:383) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:302) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:60) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:219) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1004) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:421) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at br.gov.camara.cotasgraf.controle.util.SelecaoSolicitanteFiltro.doFilter(SelecaoSolicitanteFiltro.java:58) [classes:]
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at br.gov.camara.cotasgraf.controle.util.EncodeFiltro.doFilter(EncodeFiltro.java:38) [classes:]
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at br.gov.camara.cotasgraf.controle.util.CacheFiltro.doFilter(CacheFiltro.java:42) [classes:]
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:248) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:77) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:167) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:761) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]

<p:submenu id="menu_consulta_requisicao" label="#{label['menu.requisicao.consulta']}" rendered="#{menuBB.acessoMenuReproducao.rendered or menuBB.acessoMenuServicoGrafico.rendered}">
<p:menuitem id="menu_servico_grafico_requisicao" value="#{label['paginas.requisicao.servicografico.label']}"  binding="#{menuBB.acessoMenuServicoGrafico}" ajax="false" onclick="#{menuBB.setarValores()}"/>
<p:menuitem id="menu_reproducao_requisicao" value="#{label['paginas.requisicao.prontoatendimento.label']}"  binding="#{menuBB.acessoMenuReproducao}" ajax="false" />
</p:submenu>

Comment: This question needs more detail if anyone is to have a chance helping you find a solution.   Please edit the question and add details like a stack trace, what your pom.xml looks like, and what the code looks like at the point you are seeing the NPE.

Comment: As for your other question check also if your controller is resolved and post xhtml and controller code.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the stacktraces it appears you have a 2.2.x API JAR together with a 2.1.x implementation JAR. That is never going to work. You have to make sure the API and implementation JAR use the same version.

Comment: when I put the jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1 version
I have error Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/view/ViewScoped  Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.view.ViewScoped from [Module \"org.jboss.as.jsf:main\" from local module loader

Comment: I would recommend to remove the 2.1 JARs completely and use the ones that come with WildFly. And then adjust your code where necessary.